# Heroku missing required flag: -a,

Tags: heroku

I am currently doing a project and I am having issues with heroku.

Here is the mistake that always pops up when I try to use a heroku command.

[Error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEQ0m.png)

For those of you who have had the same error, what is the possible cause for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Taking a snapshot of the error and posting it instead of the actual stack trace is a bad idea.

Answer (score 62):

- Initialise with git: `git init`
- Get the app name: `heroku apps`
- Add remote:

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

Edit:
You can also run commands without permanently adding the app

`heroku run -a your_app_name`

Comment: `heroku apps` command can be used to see all the app names \ you can connect to

Answer (score 18):

The error is for missing `app name`. You must provide your app name that you want to run. Your command should be like below:

`heroku run -a YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE`

or

`heroku run --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE`

Comment: I am relative new to Heroku and I do not understand this. When I create new app and push it to heroku, I use only "heroku open" to open my app in a browser, Why do I need --app and app_name now? Why cannot just open it with "heroku open" from app directory? I use ruby on rails.

Comment: Because, heroku cli is not specific to that working directory, instead you tell heroku to use which app.

Comment: Is it always necessary to include -app app_name? because all the answers seems to be missing -app app_name and just heroku run

Answer (score 14):

When you create a Heroku app with

```
heroku create my-app
```

you need to provide the flag (`-a`, `--app`) to the add-on installation

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app my-app
```

Answer (score 9):

whenever you run some commands for effecting your heroku application, you need to set git remote to your application to work, use that by,

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and all it required was getting into the app directory, in the app.js level

Comment: i could have commented this answer, but i dont have 50 reputations

Answer (score 3):

Yeah this worked pretty fine for just type in:

```
heroku apps
```

the app name will appear then just type in:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app YOUR_APP_NAME
```

You can also name it from the first beginning when creating it just provide the app name like so:

```
heroku create YOUR_APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply Do this,

**cd App_name/**

and then navigate to bash

***heroku run bash***

Comment: For those who end up here after stumbling across this error, this would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

adding postgres to your app:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app PROJECT_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason i got this error is that i am running heroku command out of my project location. After setting the project location in command prompt and run heroku command. Everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same kind of error every time I tried creating a variable. I was able to fix it by running these commands:

```
heroku git:remote -a <your_heroku_app_name>
heroku config:set <variable_name=value>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically telling you `Heroku` needs to know which app you want to run. So you should provide the name of the app as in below:

```
heroku run -a app_name
```

or you can also use the flag `--app` like below:

```
heroku run --app app_name
```