# 'Missing required flag' error when adding worker dyno to Heroku app

Tags: javascript, heroku, worker

I've created a simple read&respond Discord bot which works fine locally, but when i uploaded it to heroku through github it wouldn't run for more than a minute. I got this error(NOTE: my question is not how to fix this error):

> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

After research and reading other StackOverflow posts, I found that I needed to add the worker dyno to run the app 24/7. Heroku forums told me to use this:

```
 $>heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

so i tried, but i got this error message:

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\App35>heroku ps:scale worker=1
 »   Error: Missing required flag:
 »     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 »   See more help with --help
```

I tried using `-a` but then it said my app didn't exist

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\App35>heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a App35
Scaling dynos... !
 !    Couldn't find that app.
```

How can i resolve this issue? or is there another way to add worker to my app? Thank you!

Edit:

The file is found(I had a capitalization error) but now i get this error:

```
C:\Users\****\Desktop\app35> heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a app35
Scaling dynos... !
!    Couldn't find that process type (worker).
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Run `heroku apps` to see the list of apps you've got access to. You've either got the app name wrong or are logged in as the wrong user.

Comment: @ceejayoz I had a capitalization issue, thanks. But when I did it with the proper app name it says "Couldn't find that process type (worker)"

Comment: What does your `Procfile` contain?

Comment: @ceejayoz `worker: node index.js`

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815542/heroku-missing-required-flag-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter an error related to capitalization when working with Heroku, it's important to remember that Heroku is case-sensitive, and the app name and commands need to match the capitalization used when you initially created your app. Here's how to address this issue:

1. **Check App Name Capitalization**:
   Double-check the capitalization of your app name. Heroku app names are case-sensitive, so "myApp" is different from "myapp." Ensure that you're using the exact capitalization you specified when you created your Heroku app.
2. **Use the Correct App Name**:
   When running Heroku CLI commands, make sure to use the correct app name with the exact capitalization. For example:

   ```bash
   heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a YourCorrectAppName
   ```
3. **Update GitHub Repository (if applicable)**:
   If you're deploying your app from a GitHub repository, make sure that the GitHub repository name and any references to it also use the correct capitalization.
4. **Verify Procfile and File Names**:
   Check your `Procfile` and any file names within your project to ensure that they match the correct capitalization. The Procfile process types and file references should match the capitalization used in your Heroku app's configuration.
5. **Heroku Dashboard**:
   If you're still having trouble, you can also check the Heroku Dashboard. Log in to your Heroku account and navigate to the app's dashboard to confirm the correct capitalization.

By addressing capitalization errors and making sure that all references match the case of your Heroku app, you should be able to resolve the issues related to app recognition and successfully run Heroku CLI commands without encountering "Couldn't find that app" errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter a "Couldn't find that app" error on Heroku when using the `heroku ps:scale` command, it could be due to a capitalization error in your app name. Heroku app names are case-sensitive, so it's important to use the correct capitalization.

To resolve this issue, double-check the exact name of your Heroku app, including its capitalization, by running the following command:

```bash
heroku apps
```

This command will list all your Heroku apps along with their names, and it will help you confirm the correct capitalization.

Once you've identified the correct app name, you can then use it with the `heroku ps:scale` command like this:

```bash
heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a YourCorrectAppName
```

Make sure that the capitalization matches the actual app name, and you should be able to scale the worker dyno without encountering the "Couldn't find that app" error.