# How to solve clearDb creation issue in heroku

Tags: heroku, cleardb

I am new to Heroku ,I want to deploy my springBoot mysql application on heroku ,But when I try to create clearDb using heroku command it will throw an error. I want to deploy my application free on heroku. Below type of issue I found when use the create command

```
imac@Nilmanis-iMac heroku-demo-application % heroku addons:create cleardb:ignite
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

I want to deploy the application with database, But I am not able to do that.I am using mysql in my application How to create clearDb for my application

Comment: Please don't abuse Markdown for formatting. Blockquotes (`>`) mean that you're quoting something. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku missing required flag: -a,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815542/heroku-missing-required-flag-a)

Comment: See also [How to avoid the --app option with heroku CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55470675/354577) and [How does `heroku config` know what app to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50198860/354577)